# Weather app API no longer working

Tags: javascript, jquery, api-design

I'm trying to get [forecast.io](http://developer.forecast.io)'s API to work with a simple web app I'm making for Free Code Camp.

I'm having some trouble with this function:

```
function getWeather() {
   $.ajax({
      url: baseURL + key + lat + "," + lon,
      success: function () {
         console.log("the api responded with the weather :)");
         $(".desc").text("If it worked this will appear");
      }
   });
```

}

You can view the full code here: http://codepen.io/Mortiferr/pen/mPXKzZ

I have set up two checks, a console.log which worked at some point and then randomly stopped working but the jQuery `.text` never worked.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term. Define that.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I sometimes forget to explain. Anyway, the API doesn't seem to be responding properly. None of my checks are working.

Comment: You only have a `success` callback so when it doesn't succeed it'll just do nothing. Also, the first thing to check when AJAX fails is the browser's *Network* pane.

Comment: Your example is broken because you're calling `getPosition` yourself instead of letting the location API do the callback like it's supposed to.  Also please set up error handlers https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closely into your code, it seems to be a scope problem, at the begining you declare the variables `lat` and `lon` globally. I recommend you to get user's current position first and then make the API request *inside* the `navigator` function; something like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
    var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var lon = pos.coords.longitude;
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + baseURL + key + lat + "," + lon,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(x){
            console.log("the api responded with the weather :)");
            $(".desc").text("If it worked this will appear");
        }
    });
});
```

hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your example and tried with their endpoint. It seems they return JSON that contains garbled data, as there is an "**`Unexpected end of data at line 1"`** error.

Here's the modified example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzxOGq and outlined below:

```
function fahrenheitToCelsius() {
   var celsiusTemp = Math.round((temperature - 32) / 1.8);
}

function init() {
   var key = "d7294f4361b9b4f604fc3bb61e7ae763"; // please no looky
   var baseURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" // bass drop
   var lat;
   var lon;
   var url;
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
         lat = location.coords.latitude;
         lon = location.coords.longitude;

         url = baseURL + key + '/' + lat + "," + lon;

         $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cors: true,
            success: function(d) {
               console.log("the api responded with the weather :)");
               $(".desc").text("Here is the weather");
            }
         })
      });
   } else {
      alert("Sorry, geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
   }
}

init(); // batter up
```

If you try with a completely different endpoint, say **`http://date.jsontest.com/`** , it works.

There is also a note that their API has changed. If you look at their [DOCS](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2)  you see that you'll need this url scheme for it to work:

```
https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
```

So, for example this one works if you open it in your browser:

https://api.forecast.io/forecast/d7294f4361b9b4f604fc3bb61e7ae763/63.559508,10.209261

However, as I said initially, forecast.io seems to send have some issues as the xhr-requests ends up with terminated data.

Also: In your original code example, GEO is never instanced, so the console throws an error. I suggest [looking at the modified one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzxOGq) I made.

Comment: There are two types of API calls. A forecast request returns the current forecast (for the next week):

https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
A time-machine request returns the observed weather at a given time (for many places, up to 60 years in the past):

https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,TIME